# Change the hold time of the cursor?

Tags: vim, vi

When using the event trigger `CursorHoldI` I found that it takes about 3 seconds to execute the command.

Is there a way to decrease this time ?

Comment: You're probably after `:help timeout` or maybe `:help updatetime` (based on what the manual for CursorHold says)

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelBerkowski `updatetime` was the solution.

Answer (score 13):

From [`:help CursorHoldI`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorHoldI):

```
Just like CursorHold, but in Insert mode. [..]
```

And then from [`:help CursorHold`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorHold):

```
CursorHold                      When the user doesn't press a key for the time
                                specified with 'updatetime'.
[..]
```

The default for `updatetime` is 4000 (4 seconds); you can change this to something like 1 second:

```
set updatetime=1000
```

Note that a very low value may slow Vim down, as some `CursorHold` commands may be comparatively expensive. It's also used for writing the swap file